# How to scale an image dynamically using canvas

Tags: html, image, canvas, pixel

I am trying to resize an image based on the canvas size. My code is below. The issue is that when I try to drawImage(), it draws fine but the pixels get distorted within the image.
Any help would be highly appreciated!! I have been trying to do a lot of things like manipulating pixels using canvas imageData but with no luck at all :(

```
var imgURL = $('img#AS0017CF5A').attr('src');
                imgH = $('img#AS0017CF5A').height();
                imgW = $('img#AS0017CF5A').width();
                $('img#AS0017CF5A').parent().attr('id','pImg');
                $('img#AS0017CF5A').hide();

                imageObj = new Image();

                imageObj.onload = function(ev) {

                   document.getElementById('pImg').innerHTML = '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="' + imgW + '" height="' + imgH + '"></canvas>';
                    var toto = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                    var c = toto.getContext("2d");
                    c.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imgW, imgH);

                   //context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.width, imageObj.height, 0, 0, imgW, imgH);                 
                };
                imageObj.src = imgURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me :

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "icon.png";
img.onload = function()
{
    document.body.innerHTML = '<canvas id="toto" width="' + img.width + '" height="' + img.height + '"></canvas>';
    var toto = document.getElementById("toto");
    var c = toto.getContext("2d");
    c.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
```

Maybe it's JQuery which failed created the canvas correctly ?

And be sure to not have any width/height in your css set on your canvas.

Comment: It still does not work. The image which gets rendered in the canvas has some text blurred in it opposed to how it gets displayed when rendered in an image tag. Please help!!! :(

Comment: Have you an exemple somewhere which does not work ?
When you print the width/height of your canvas in your onload function are they the same than your image size ?

Comment: I tried to edit the question above with the code I used after ur reply. When I create the canvas dynamically, I tried to do so with the required scale height and width and then drawing the image with the same height and width

Comment: If your canvas has the same size than your image there is no reason that it does not work, except if you have any CSS which changes that. Maybe try to force the css width/height of your canvas, or maybe the .width() of JQuery does crazy tricks ?

Comment: Actually, the image is 774x348 and the canvas size I am setting is 320x192 (which is the required dimension for scaling the image). Hence the original image dimensions are not the same as the canvas but the image is tried to be scaled to 320x192. So what is happening here is I am trying to reduce the size of the image through canvas dynamically but it does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Ok you want to scale it, you didn't precised that :)
The ratio of your canvas is not the same as your image, that's why a scale is made and turns it blurry.
Try following this example : http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/LjhdU/
(found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087483/how-to-proportionally-resize-an-image-in-canvas)

Comment: Hm so if there is no CSS applied to this or a parent I really don't know what happened, without any web page I can see I'll not able to help you more, I think the problem is above in your project because there is no reason to have bad dimensions if you keep the correct ratio of your image in your canvas.

Comment: yes you are correct. The other issue here is that I am using a custom lockdown browser and the images have a outset border(although forcibly blocked by css) and thats the reason why I shifted to canvas. But by using canvas, the borders are gone but the image pixels get distorted. Hence I am not sure what next approach to take. Whatever solution I do, it works in all browsers but not in lockdown...